# Calculate minimum distance between groups of points in data frame

Tags: r

my data frame looks like this:

```
Time, Value, Group
0, 1.0, A
1, 2.0, A
2, 3.0, A
0, 4.0, B
1, 6.0, B
2, 6.0, B
0, 7.0, C
1, 7.0, C
2, 9.0, C
```

I need to find for each combination (A, B), (A, C), (B, C) the maximum difference over each corresponding `Time` points.

So comparing A and B has maximum distance for t=1 which is 6 (B) - 2 (A) = 4.

The full output should be something like this:

```
combination,time,distance
AB, 0, 4
AC, 0, 6
BC, 0, 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way in base R using `combn` :

```
do.call(rbind, combn(unique(df$Group), 2, function(x) {
  df1 <- subset(df, Group == x[1])
  df2 <- subset(df, Group == x[2])
  df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'Time')
  value <- abs(df3$Value.x - df3$Value.y)
  data.frame(combn = paste(x, collapse = ''), 
             time = df3$Time[which.max(value)],
             max_difference = max(value))
}, simplify = FALSE))

#  combn time max_difference
#1    AB    1              4
#2    AC    0              8
#3    BC    0              5
```

We create all combination of `unique` `Group` values, `subset` the data for them and `merge` them on `Time`. Subtract the corresponding value columns and return the `max` difference between them.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Time = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 9), Group = c("A", "A", 
    "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Do I need to adjust -9L to the number of row in my data frame?

Comment: `-9L` from the `dput` (data) that I have shared at the end? No, that is the data that I have used to test my solution. You probably already have your data.

Comment: Ah okay, I thought I need to adjust this, now it's working as expected. Neat!

Comment: No, the combinations are fine. I want to include all pairs, but they are symmetric, so I do need only one of (A, B) and (B,A) but not both. @RonakShah how would I modify this to consider only these pairs: (A, B), (A, C)?

Comment: @Henrik I want to get all 2-combinations of the set {A, B, C}.

Comment: Yes, but I apparently misunderstood the "over _each_ corresponding Time". I expected _each_ time to be analysed separately, and that e.g. Time 2 should appear in the output, like in @tmfmnk answer.

Comment: @Henrik sorry for this, yes the time points need to match. If you have advise to improve my question so it is easier to understand, go ahead and edit it. But what I did not add in the first place is: I would also need to filter for combinations which have "A" as the first element of the 2-combination for another task. Possibly it would be great if I could do this without a postprocessing.

Comment: At the very least you should edit your question and show the desired output, to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221311/discussion-between-stephanmg-and-henrik).

Comment: @stephanmg You should not edit your question to ask additional question. Instead ask it as a new question.

Comment: @RonakShah okay, I changed it back. The filtering can be done by `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 inner_join(df, by = "Time") %>%
 filter(Group.x != Group.y) %>%
 group_by(Time,
          Group = paste(pmax(Group.x, Group.y), pmin(Group.x, Group.y), sep = "-")) %>%
 summarise(Max_Distance = abs(max(Value.x[Group.x == first(Group.x)]) -  max(Value.y[Group.y == first(Group.y)])))

   Time Group Max_Distance
  <int> <chr>        <dbl>
1     0 B-A              3
2     0 C-A              8
3     0 C-B              5
4     1 B-A              4
5     2 B-A              3
```

Comment: This option works as well for me. Also I did not explicitly state I do not want to use additional dependencies, e.g. using plain vanilla R, I upvoted this as well. Thanks!